# Thread-safe lock striping over mutable object store in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have implemented a thread-safe mutable object store with a simple API. Intuitively it has performance limitations, namely lock contention with multiple concurrent writers. First though, here is the API:

```
new :: String -> IO Int
get :: Int -> IO (Maybe String)
delete :: Int -> IO ()
```

Hidden within the implementation is a globally accessible `IORef` holding a pure data structure `Ref`, exposed with `unsafePerformIO`. It is an `IntMap`, and an incremented slot number. When an element is added to the `IntMap`, the slot is incremented and returned as a reference to the entry. Here is the implementation:

```
module MyModule (new,get,delete) where

import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Data.IORef
import qualified Data.IntMap as Map
import Data.Functor ((<$>))
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

new :: String -> IO Int
new = atomicModifyIORef ref . createEntry

get :: Int -> IO (Maybe String)
get i = liftM (Map.lookup i) (table <$> readIORef ref)

delete :: Int -> IO ()
delete = atomicModifyIORef ref . deleteEntry

---------------
-- IORef mutation

data Ref = Ref { lastSlot :: !Int , table :: Map.IntMap String }

{-# NOINLINE ref #-}
ref :: IORef Ref
ref = unsafePerformIO $
        newIORef Ref { lastSlot = 0, table = Map.empty }

createEntry :: String -> Ref -> (Ref, Int)
createEntry val reg =
  ref `seq` (reg', newSlot) where
    newSlot = lastSlot reg + 1
    reg' = reg { lastSlot = newSlot,
                 table    = Map.insert newSlot val (table reg) }

deleteEntry :: Int -> Ref -> (Ref, ())
deleteEntry slot reg = (reg { table = Map.delete slot (table reg) }, ())
```

An example of use is:

```
test :: IO ()
test = do
    x <- new "foo"
    y <- new "bar"
    fromJust <$> get y >>= print -- prints "bar"
    fromJust <$> get x >>= print -- prints "foo"
    delete x >> delete y
```

This is thread safe e.g. `new` can be called in separate threads. And this works. As pointed out by **Gregory Collins**, The problem is *contention*. When there are 100k+ entries added in the multiple-concurrent-writers case, `atomicModifyIORef` will swap the value out with a thunk. Then when I try to use the `IntMap` underneath the `IORef`, multiple mutators will attempt to force the value to WHNF, either resulting in duplicated work or threads blocking on a "blackhole", which is bad either way.

What I'm looking for is an alternative implementation, leaving the types for `new`, `get`, and `delete` unaffected. One possibility is to use lock-striping, to reduce lock contention. [This HashMap implementation](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-server/blob/3e6ae43c5d8ab64ebb802dc1eb65bae9afe30efe/src/Data/Concurrent/HashMap.hs) in the snap framework implements lock-striping, by partitioning the key or hash space into N partitions (i.e. `Vector (MVar (HashTable k v))`) and then guards each with a mutex lock. It's not clear to me how I'd re-implement `new`,`get` and `delete` in my module using this HashMap, without modifying the types (which would break a lot of modules that use it).

- Are there any thread-safe Haskell concurrent object store or HashMap libraries that I could use to re-implement my API?
- I'd like to remove the `unsafePerformIO`.
- I'd very much prefer to stay within the IO Monad for my API.

Comment: Have you looked at `Control.Concurrent.STM` ?

Comment: You should use the `NOINLINE` pragma on `ref`, otherwise the compiler might inline it with some very strange behaviour as a result. For possible alternatives for `unsafePerformIO` you can look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Top_level_mutable_state, though sometimes `unsafePerformIO` it is just the best option.

Comment: @Laar thanks. In fact, my implementation *does* used `NOINLINE`, though I did not copy this across. I have edited the code above to include it. re: `unsafePerformIO`, my question still remains: I want lock-striping across my `IntMap` access and mutations. I'm not sure whether having a striped keyspace across mutable buckets is lost if all buckets are in a global `IORef`..

Comment: If your issue is thunks building up on the `IntMap`, try importing `Data.IntMap.Strict` and adding strictness to the `table` field in `Ref`.